# Why won't my Orbeon 4.4 Form Runner "push to remote" work?

Tags: weblogic, orbeon, weblogic11g

I am running Orbeon on 2 Weblogic 11g application servers, and have tried to configure remote publishing and pushing/pulling forms between them.

I have followed this guide:

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Home-Page

(See section "Remote Server Operations")

The only difference is that the example they give for setting up the "orbeon-admin" user with a role of "orbeon-service" is for Tomcat.  I have tried to set up the exact thing on Weblogic using the Weblogic Console, and configuring the appropriate security roles and users.

I am able to connect from one form-runner to the other, the login prompt appears and I am able to successfully login and see the Form Runner page with the "local" and "remote" columns showing the state of each for on both the local and remote Orbeon instance.

I am able to successfully pull forms down from the remote server to the local server.

I am also able to publish and unpublish forms on the remote server.

What I cannot do however, is PUSH forms from the local server to the remote server.  When I try and do so, it appears to have worked, ie I get a spinner for a few seconds, then no error appears, however the form does not end up on the remote server.

The Orbeon logs on the "local" machine give the following exception:

```
2014-12-04 14:24:18,151 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "or
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|xf:submission for submission id: read-form, error code received when submitting instance: 401                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|getReplacer                   |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 733|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        | 101|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           |  99|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 124|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 464|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 296|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 137|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  38|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |dispatchEvent                 |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
|g.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsSendAction|execute                       |XFormsSendAction.scala        |  51|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAction          |execute                       |XFormsAction.scala            |  36|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runSingleIteration            |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 205|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runAction                     |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 151|
|ction.actions.XFormsActionAction$$anonfun$execute$1|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  53|
|ction.actions.XFormsActionAction$$anonfun$execute$1|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  41|
|scala.collection.Iterator$class                    |foreach                       |Iterator.scala                | 727|
|scala.collection.AbstractIterator                  |foreach                       |Iterator.scala                |1157|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService             |service                       |ProcessorService.scala        |  41|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  74|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              | 118|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 820|
|et.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction|run                           |StubSecurityHelper.java       | 227|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper       |invokeServlet                 |StubSecurityHelper.java       | 125|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl          |execute                       |ServletStubImpl.java          | 301|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl          |execute                       |ServletStubImpl.java          | 184|
|ternal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction|wrapRun                       |WebAppServletContext.java     |3729|
|ternal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction|run                           |WebAppServletContext.java     |3696|
|weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject|doAs                          |AuthenticatedSubject.java     | 321|
|weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager          |runAs                         |SecurityManager.java          | 120|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext     |securedExecute                |WebAppServletContext.java     |2273|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext     |execute                       |WebAppServletContext.java     |2179|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl       |run                           |ServletRequestImpl.java       |1490|
|weblogic.work.ExecuteThread                        |execute                       |ExecuteThread.java            | 256|
|weblogic.work.ExecuteThread                        |run                           |ExecuteThread.java            | 221|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
```

Comment: Surprising. The 401 indicates that there the request is unauthorized. But in that case, pulling shouldn't work either.

Comment: Yes which is why I'm confused... I would have expected nothing to work if the auth is failing.